# Erro ao atribuir valores dinâmicos ao componente TUniConnection da UniDAC

Tags: delphi, conexão

Usando os componente da UniDAC para o Delphi XE5, encontrei um erro ao atribuir valores dinâmicos para o componente TUniConnection, responsável pela conexão com o banco de dados.

A mensagem de erro surge após a linha Connected := True;

dm = DataModule onde está o componente.

```
try
  with dm.conServer do
  begin
    Server := 'localhost';
    Port := 5432;
    Username := 'postgres';
    Password := 'postgres';
    Database := 'newserver';
    Connected := True;
  end;
except
  on E: Exception do
    ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ' Erro : ' + E.Message);
end;
```

[image: Código e Erro]

Está faltando algum parâmetro? O que eu estaria fazendo errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O exemplo retirado do site da UniDac, mostra como realizar a conexão:

```
var
  UniConnection1: TUniConnection;
...
UniConnection1.ProviderName := 'Oracle';
UniConnection1.Username := 'scott';
UniConnection1.Password := 'tiger';
UniConnection1.Server := 'ORA1020';
UniConnection1.SpecificOptions.Values['Schema'] := 'SCOTT';
UniConnection1.Open;
```

> Cada linha da propriedade SpecificOptions tem o seguinte formato: =. >Você pode adicionar opções também usando o método `Add`:

```
UniConnection1.SpecificOptions.Add('Schema=SCOTT');
```

Fonte: http://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/index.html?basics.htm

Só uma dica. O uso do `with` é perigoso, pois ele não garante que as propriedades que você está setando são do Objeto definido no with. Se ele não encontrar no with, ele procura no Self automaticamente. Além de dificultar o debug.

Comment: @AlexSchmitt, sempre às órdens :D

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, me foram muito úteis, mas infelizmente ainda não resolveu o problema, o erro persiste.

Comment: vou migrar para FireDAC, acredito ser uma solução boa, além de nativa. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver o problema usando o FireDAC.

Componentes usados:
TFDGUIxWaitCursor, TFDPhysPgDriverLink e TFDConnection.

Uses: System.IniFiles

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  appINI: TIniFile;
  Server, Username, Password, Database: String;
  Port: Integer;
begin
  direxe := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName));
  appINI := TIniFile.Create(direxe + 'config.ini');
  try
    Server := appINI.ReadString('Server', 'Server', '');
    Port := appINI.ReadInteger('Server', 'Port', 5432);
    Username := appINI.ReadString('Server', 'Username', '');
    Password := appINI.ReadString('Server', 'Password', '');
    Database := appINI.ReadString('Server', 'Database', '');
  finally
    appINI.Free;
    try
      dm.conServer.DriverName := 'PG';
      dm.conServer.Params.Add('Server=' + Server);
      dm.conServer.Params.Add('Port=' + IntToStr(Port));
      dm.conServer.Params.Add('Database=' + Database);
      dm.conServer.Params.Add('User_name=' + Username);
      dm.conServer.Params.Add('Password=' + Password);
      dm.conServer.Connected := True;
    except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ' Erro : ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```